# ¿Cómo puedo sumar todos los números de un vector?

Tags: javascript

Estoy haciendo un proyecto, pero necesito que todos los números que están almacenados en un vector se sumen Ej:[2,4,12,24,52] resultado:94. He estado intentándolo con el bucle for, pero no entiendo qué debo hacer. Como verán en el código la cantidad de datos que están en el vector va aumentando, por eso necesito que se sumen todos los elementos que estén en le vector. De antemano muchas gracias.

```js
let array=[];
function entrada() {
 let array1=[];
 let transformacion=[];
let texto1=document.getElementById('entrada1').value;
let texto2=document.getElementById('entrada2').value;
let texto3=document.getElementById('entrada3').value;
 array1.push(texto1,texto2,texto3);
 array1.forEach((elemento) => {
            transformacion.push(Number(elemento))
          });
 array.push(transformacion);
 console.log(array)
 aparicion();
}
//*************************PROCESO DE VISUALIZACIÓN-ESTÉTICA************************************
function aparicion(){
 let texto1=document.getElementById('entrada1').value;
 let texto2= document.getElementById('entrada2').value;
 let texto3= document.getElementById('entrada3').value;
 document.getElementById('tabla').innerHTML+=`<tr><td>${texto1}</td><td class="suma">${texto2}</td><td>${texto3}</td></tr>`;
 // document.getElementById('r2').innerHTML+=`<td>${texto1}</td>`
 // document.getElementById('r3').innerHTML+=`<td>${texto1}</td>`
 sumar();
}
//*******************************PARTE OPERACIONAL-FUNCIONAL*************************************************
let hombre="";
function sumar(num){
 hombre=[];
 // document.getElementById('hola').innerHTML=`<h5>${array}</5>`;
 for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  if (array.length>=0) {
   // console.log(array[i][0]);
   hombre.push(array[i][0]);
   // document.getElementById('hola').innerHTML=`<h5>${array[i][0]}</h5>`;
   
  }


 }
 console.log(hombre);
} 
 let n="";
function tr(){
 // hombre
 for (var i =0;i<=hombre.length ; i++) {
  if (hombre.length>=0) {
   n=(hombre+[i]);
  };
  if (i>=1){
   
   console.log(hombre[i]+hombre[1]);
  }
 }
 // console.log(n);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes proceder así:

- Toma el vector `hombre` que se esta llenando dinámicamente de valores y usa el método `reduce()` para hacer la sumatoria de todos los elementos, reduciendo todo el contenido a un único elemento

Así:

```js
let valores = [1,2,3]

let suma = valores.reduce((pasado, presente) => pasado + presente)

console.log(suma)
```

Lo que ocurre:

- `reduce()` sigue siendo un ciclo o bucle, es decir que itera sobre todos los elementos del vector actual
- Dicho método<sup>1</sup> recibe cuatro argumentos según la documentación oficial; nosotros nos concentraremos en:

  - pasado: Que sería el valor actual que tiene el bucle al momento de iterar el vector, que en este caso sería `1`
  - presente: Que sería el valor que esta en la siguiente posición del vector, es decir el `2`
  - En la siguiente vuelta se sumarían las posiciones anteriores dando 3
  - En la siguiente vuelta tenemos 3 de valor acumulado y se lo sumamos al valor presente que es `3` y es el último elemento del vector

Lo anterior visualmente podría verse así:

```
/*pasado   presente
    1        2
    3        3 acumulado de los dos anteriores
    6        nada se nos acabaron los elementos del vector XD
*/
```

**Referencias**

- <sup>1</sup>[Método `reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/reduce)

Answer (score 3):

Es tan simple como tener una variable temporal a la que le vas a ir sumando cada uno de los elementos del array, por ejemplo:

```
let arreglo = [2, 4, 12, 24, 52];
var temp = 0;
for (let i = 0; i < arreglo.length; i++) {
    temp += arreglo[i];
}
console.log(temp);
```